# Sumproduct with multiple criteria on one range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In a dataset I have answers that participants to a survey gave. The answers are in one example numbered 1 to 5, with 1 being yes, and 2 to 5 being variants of no.

20 or so similar questions have been asked, and participants can be in either one of 20 subgroups. Questions were categorized into 6 classes.

Now the best way to go about such a dataset would normally be the use of a pivot-table, however the way the data is set up doesn't work with a pivot table, and due to the sheer size of the dataset remodelling isn't efficient.

To extract the amount of people in a certain subgroup that answered yes for questions in a certain class I use the following function:

```
=SuMPRODUCT(--(Test!D$4:$CC$1824=1)*(Test!$C$4:$C$1824=$C3)*(Test!$D$3:$CC$3=D$2))
```

In which `Test!D$4:$CC$1824` is the range where answers are given, and the other two are ranges for subgroup and classes respectively.

By using `--(Test!D$4:$CC$1824=1)` I convert all data to 0's except for where participants answered yes (cell value = 1).

Now I would like to do the same thing for where they answered no, so the value is either 2 or 3 or 4 or 5. The ideal way would be to append some OR logic into the first test, coming about something like this: `--(Test!D$4:$CC$1824={2,3,4,5})`

Ofcourse this doesn't work, but is there any simple notation besides retyping the first part 4 times, and adding them together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OR operation can be mimicked by adding all of the possibilities together.

```
=SuMPRODUCT(((Test!D$4:$CC$1824=2)+(Test!D$4:$CC$1824=3)+(Test!D$4:$CC$1824=4)+(Test!D$4:$CC$1824=5))*
            (Test!$C$4:$C$1824=$C3)*(Test!$D$3:$CC$3=D$2))
```

If there is any possibilitiy that two could be correct (in this case there isn't) wrap the sum in the SIGN function to get only zero or one.

```
=SuMPRODUCT(SIGN((Test!D$4:$CC$1824=2)+(Test!D$4:$CC$1824=3)+(Test!D$4:$CC$1824=4)+(Test!D$4:$CC$1824=5))*
            (Test!$C$4:$C$1824=$C3)*(Test!$D$3:$CC$3=D$2))
```

Comment: you are right, I forgot about the `Or` ability of `SUMPRODUCT` by adding the conditions with `+`

Comment: Your hint of Sign did the trick. I'm not sure how data came to fulfil multiple criteria, but comparing by doing them individually for all 4, and summing that showed rather large differences. Using `Sign` made all differences 0.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say you could just use `>1` instead of `=1`

For selected results like 1 and 3 and 5 you probably need to add the sumproducts of each number.

Sidenote: the `--` is not necessary anymore as it is just for converting `true` and `false` to `1` and `0` when there is only one bracket inside `sumproduct`

Comment: maybe `<>1` is another option.

Comment: @Jeeped, good suggestion, but in my case a lot off cells have been filled by vba with `""` so those get counted as well.

Comment: @Luuklag, Well, `"">1` appears true so `>1` doesn't appear valid in that scenario. Sorry OverflowStacker.

Comment: @Jeeped you never cease to learn :)   Then the `<>""` condition might be handy too