# SIGN() formula returns unexpected results

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In continuation of my previous question: [Sumproduct with multiple criteria on one range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52664223/sumproduct-with-multiple-criteria-on-one-range)

Jeeped provided me with an very helpful formula to achieve a `sumproduct()` which takes multiple criteria. My current case is however a bit broader:

Take these example tables:

First column is the ID number, second column a respondent group(A,B). Column headers are question types (X,Y,Z).

**Table Q1**

```
|    |   | X | Y | Y | Z | Y |
|----|---|---|---|---|---|---|
| 1  | A | 2 | 2 | 1 |   | 1 |
| 2  | A | 1 | 1 |   |   | 2 |
| 3  | A | 1 | 1 |   |   | 1 |
| 4  | A | 2 | 1 |   |   | 1 |
| 5  | A | 1 | 2 | 1 |   | 1 |
| 6  | A | 1 | 1 |   |   | 1 |
| 7  | A |   |   |   |   |   |
| 8  | A |   |   |   |   |   |
| 9  | A | 1 | 1 |   |   | 1 |
| 10 | A | 2 | 2 | 2 |   | 2 |
| 11 | A |   |   |   |   |   |
| 12 | A | 1 | 2 | 1 |   | 2 |
| 13 | B |   |   |   |   |   |
| 14 | B | 1 | 1 |   |   | 1 |
| 15 | B | 2 | 2 | 1 |   | 1 |
```

**Table Q2**

```
|    |   | X | Y | Y | Z | Y |
|----|---|---|---|---|---|---|
| 1  | A | 1 | 2 | 1 |   | 1 |
| 2  | A | 1 | 1 |   |   | 1 |
| 3  | A | 1 | 1 |   |   | 1 |
| 4  | A | 1 | 1 |   |   | 1 |
| 5  | A | 1 | 1 |   |   | 1 |
| 6  | A | 1 | 1 |   |   | 1 |
| 7  | A |   |   |   |   |   |
| 8  | A |   |   |   |   |   |
| 9  | A | 1 | 1 |   |   | 1 |
| 10 | A | 1 | 1 |   |   | 1 |
| 11 | A |   |   |   |   |   |
| 12 | A | 1 | 2 | 1 |   | 1 |
| 13 | B |   |   |   |   |   |
| 14 | B | 1 | 1 |   |   | 1 |
| 15 | B | 1 | 2 | 1 |   | 1 |
```

Now I want to know the amount of times a respondent answered 1 (yes) on Q2 for each question type (X,Y,Z). The catch is that if someone answered 1 (yes) on Q1 it should "override" the answer on Q2, as we assume that when someone answers yes on Q1 (implementation of a measure), their answer on Q2 (knowledge of said measure) has to be yes as well.

The second catch is that for the first two occurrences of Y there can only be yes in one of both columns, so in fact there can only be two yes answers for question type Y for each respondent.

I used the following formula (on sheet 3): `=SUMPRODUCT(SIGN(('Q1'!$C$2:$G$16=1)+('Q2'!$C$2:$G$16=1))*('Q2'!$B$2:$B$16=Blad3!$D5)*('Q2'!$C$1:$G$1=Blad3!E$4))` to obtain the following results.

```
|   | X | Y  | Z |
|---|---|----|---|
| A | 9 | 19 | 0 |
| B | 2 | 4  | 0 |
```

For X these results are correct, as there are 9 1's in table Q2.
For Y the results for B are correct, for A however they are not, as there are only 9 respondents, answering max 2 questions would result in a max of 18, we have 19 however.

Comment: Try to narrow your statement down to a specific problem. And provide an example by which we can reproduce your problem.  Perhaps [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will provide some guidance.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld you are right, I mocked up some dummy data and revised the Q

Comment: What is the significance of the third `Y` column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there is nothing wrong with the formula, just that it isn't suited for the way this data is organised. If you look at row 5:

Q1

```
|    |   | X | Y | Y | Z | Y |
|----|---|---|---|---|---|---|
| 5  | A | 1 | 2 | 1 |   | 1 |
```

Q2

```
|    |   | X | Y | Y | Z | Y |
|----|---|---|---|---|---|---|
| 5  | A | 1 | 1 |   |   | 1 |
```

If we condense that to everywhere there is a 1 in any of the Y column we get this table:

```
|    |   | X | Y | Y | Z | Y |
|----|---|---|---|---|---|---|
| 5  | A |   | 1 | 1 |   | 1 |
```

When I ask for the `sumproduct()` for this combined table the result will be 3.

To prevent this I added a helper column (between the two Y and the Z column) to my tables, with the following formula: `IF(OR(D1=1,E1=1),1,"")`. Removed the headers from the double Y columns, and re-running the query produced the correct results.

New table Q1 looks like this then:

```
|    |   | X |   |   | Y | Z | Y |
|----|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|
| 1  | A | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 |   | 1 |
| 2  | A | 1 | 1 |   | 1 |   | 2 |
| 3  | A | 1 | 1 |   | 1 |   | 1 |
| 4  | A | 2 | 1 |   | 1 |   | 1 |
| 5  | A | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 |   | 1 |
| 6  | A | 1 | 1 |   | 1 |   | 1 |
| 7  | A |   |   |   |   |   |   |
| 8  | A |   |   |   |   |   |   |
| 9  | A | 1 | 1 |   | 1 |   | 1 |
| 10 | A | 2 | 2 | 2 |   |   | 2 |
| 11 | A |   |   |   |   |   |   |
| 12 | A | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 |   | 2 |
| 13 | B |   |   |   |   |   |   |
| 14 | B | 1 | 1 |   | 1 |   | 1 |
| 15 | B | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 |   | 1 |
```